# Как в шаблон joomla добавить свой скрипт?

Tags: jquery, скрипт, joomla, javascript

Каким методом можно в шаблон joomla добавить свой скрипт, например js (или jQuery) или Ajax? Как правильно организовать их правильную работу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по формулировке вопроса, "js (или jQuery) или Ajax", освоение технологий пока в самом начале. В код шаблона можно вставить любые скрипты — он пишется как html страница, со специальными тегами для позиций модулей и компонента. Подключаемые скрипты сама Joomla вставляет перед закрывающим тегом `</head>`, поэтому, заботясь об отсутствии конфликтов напр. jQuery и MooTools, исходите из того, что те могут появиться позже.

Правильный способ подключать скрипты — через метод JDocument [addScriptDeclaration()](http://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/addScriptDeclaration).